# Create an instance in a class method in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization, factory

I am trying to create `DataType` class to reflect data types in a SQL database. Since data types require different information like `size`, `precision` etc. different parameters need to be specified when creating an instance.

I want to be able to call it with something like `DataType.createVarChar(size, charSet)`. So far I have written the code below but I am not sure whether it is the correct way to do it since I am originally creating an object at the start without providing any information in it.

What would be the correct design in this case?

```
class SQLDatatype(Enum):
    UNSUPPORTED,
    VARCHAR


class DataType(object):

    def __init__(self, dataType=None, precision=None, scale=None, size=None, charSet=None):
        self.dataType = dataType
        self.precision = precision
        self.scale = scale
        self.size = size
        self.withLocalTimezone = withLocalTimezone
        self.charSet = charSet

    def createVarChar(self, size, charSet):
        return Datatype(dataType=SQLDataType.VARCHAR, size=size, charSet=charSet)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way would be to create a function:

```
def createVarChar(size, charSet):
    return Datatype(dataType=SQLDataType.VARCHAR, size=size, charSet=charSet)
```

The other option is to create a class method:

```
class DataType(object):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def createVarChar(cls, size, charSet):
        return cls(dataType=SQLDataType.VARCHAR, size=size, charSet=charSet)
```

This allows this method to work correctly with inheritance, which a free function would not.

Comment: okay lets say i for instance wanted to have a `toString()` function inside the class aswell where i converted the datatype to for instance `varchar({}).format(size)` would that mean i had to make the `def createVarChar` outside or can is there anyway where i can get `dataType` inside another function in class?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `@classmethod`:

```
@classmethod
def createVarChar(cls, size, charSet):
    return cls(dataType=SQLDataType.VARCHAR, size=size, charSet=charSet)
```